# Converting Timezones from UTC

Tags: php

I'm having trouble converting timezone's from UTC to a user selected timezone. The problem seems to be Daylight Savings Time.

Here is an example I just coded.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

$timezone = -5.0;
$timestamp = time();

$local_time = $timezone * 3600 + $timestamp;

echo date( "m/d/Y - h:i A", $local_time );

?>
```

When I run the test file it returns `07/21/2014 - 04:29 PM`. The current time is actually 5:29. The problem is Daylight Savings Time, where our clocks are turned back an hour.

**How can I remedy this problem, or is there a more effective method for adjusting timestamps?**

Easiest solution I see is making users select whether DST is currently in effect where they live, as not every country/timezone uses DST. If it is in effect then simply modifying the `$timezone` variable to +1 would suffice, but would require each user to manage whether DST is in effect or not.

Thank-you in advance.

**EDIT:**

I tried using DateTime but it was still off...

```
<?php

$timestamp = time();

echo 'Unix timestamp: ' . $timestamp . "<br/>";
echo 'Unix date: ' . date( "m/d/Y - h:i A", $timestamp ) . "<br/><br/>";

$dt = date_create_from_format('U', $timestamp);

date_timezone_set($dt, new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

$adjusted_timestamp = date_format($dt, 'U') + date_offset_get($dt);

echo 'America/New_York: ' . $adjusted_timestamp . "<br/>";
echo 'America/New_York: ' . date( "m/d/Y - h:i A", $adjusted_timestamp );

?>
```

The results were off by +2 hours. Returns 7:47 PM, it is currently 5:47 PM.

```
Unix timestamp: 1405979278
Unix date: 07/21/2014 - 11:47 PM

America/New_York: 1405964878
America/New_York: 07/21/2014 - 07:47 PM
```

Comment: use the [DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime) object. it's far more intelligent about stuff like timezones than the simplistic date_*()-type functions are.

Comment: @MarcB hit the nail on the head. There are many exceptions to the rule that your code isn't taking into account.

Comment: I tried doing DateTime but it was off. I'll edit OP.

Comment: What is `$adjusted_timestamp`? The timestamp is exactly the same at every given moment on every place on the globe.

Comment: How old is your PHP, as well? Politicians have been mucking with DST start/end dates for years now, and your PHP may have outdated rules. PHP may be entirely correct, as far as it's been told.

Comment: XAMPP: 1.8.2 
PHP: 5.4.16